# How do I sense if my unit test is a member of an ordered test and, if it is, which position in that ordered test it is at?

Tags: automation, visual-studio-2010, c#

**Environment:**

I have a program - named CSIS - which I need to run a lot of automated tests on in Visual Studio 2010 using C#. I have a series of functions which need to be run in many different orders but which all start and end at the same 'home screen' of CSIS. The tests will either be run on their own as a single CodedUITest (*.cs filetype) or as an ordered test (*.orderedtest filetype).

**Goal:**

The goal is to open to the CSIS homepage once no matter which of the unit tests is run first and then, after all CodedUITests are finished, no matter which unit test is last, the automated test will close CSIS. I don't want to create a separate unit test to open CSIS to the homepage and another to close CSIS as this is very inconvenient for testers to use.

**Current Solution Development:**

*UPDATE:* The new big question is how do I get '[ClassInitialize]' to work?

**Additional Thoughts:**

*UPDATE:* I now just need ClassInitialize to execute code at the beginning and ClassCleanUp to execute code at the end of a test set.

If you would like the actual code let me know.

***Research Update:***

Because of Izcd's answer I was able to more accurately research the answer to my own question. I've found an answer online to my problem.

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to implement it in my code. I pasted the code as shown below in the 'Code' section of this question and the test runs fine except that it executes the OpenWindow() and CloseWindow() functions after each test instead of around the whole test set. So ultimately the code does nothing new. How do I fix this?

static private UIMap sharedTest = new UIMap();

```
[ClassInitialize] 
static public void ClassInit(TestContext context) 
{ 
    Playback.Initialize(); 
    try 
    { 
        sharedTest.OpenCustomerKeeper(); 

    } 
    finally 
    { 
        Playback.Cleanup(); 
    } 

}
```

=====================================================================================

```
Code
```

namespace CSIS_TEST
{
    //a ton of 'using' statements are here

```
public partial class UIMap
{
    #region Class Initializization and Cleanup
    static private UIMap sharedTest = new UIMap();

    [ClassInitialize]
    static public void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        try
        {
            sharedTest.OpenWindow();
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    static public void ClassCleanup()
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        try
        {

            sharedTest.CloseWindow();
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer after a very long process of asking questions on StackOverflow, Googling, and just screwing around with the code.

The answer is to use **AssemblyInitialize** and **AssemblyCleanup** and to write the code for them inside the *DatabaseSetup.cs* file which should be auto-generated in your project. You should find that there already is a AssemblyInitialize function in here but it is very basic and there is no AssemblyCleanup after it. All you need to do is create a static copy of your UIMap and use it inside the AssemblyInitialize to run your OpenWindow() code.

Copy the format of the AssemblyInitialize function to create an AssemblyCleanup function and add your CloseWindow() function.

Make sure your Open/CloseWindow functions only contains basic code (such as Process.Start/Kill) as any complex variables such as forms have been cleaned up already and won't work.

Here is the code in my DatabaseSetup.cs:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.UnitTesting;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
using Mouse = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse;
using MouseButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons;

namespace CSIS_TEST
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class DatabaseSetup
    {
        static private UIMap uIMap = new UIMap();
        static int count = 0;

        [AssemblyInitialize()]
        public static void InitializeAssembly(TestContext ctx)
        {
            DatabaseTestClass.TestService.DeployDatabaseProject();
            DatabaseTestClass.TestService.GenerateData();

            if(count < 1)
                uIMap.OpenWindow();
            count++;
        }

        [AssemblyCleanup()]
        public static void InitializeAssembly()
        {            
            uIMap.CloseWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's unit testing framework includes ClassInitialise and ClassCleanUp attributes which can be used to indicate methods that execute functionality before and after a test run.
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517.aspx )

Rather than try and make the unit tests aware of their position, I would suggest it might be better to embed the opening and closing logic of the home screen within the aforementioned ClassInitialise and ClassCleanUp marked methods.

Comment: Hey, so I've read through everything on 'ClassInitialize' on the Microsoft website and I'm having trouble actually applying it to my code.


I've added "[ClassInitialize()]" on top of my "public void OpenWindow()" in my "UIMap.cs", see below:


[ClassInitialize()]
public void OpenWindow()
{ ... }

        
When I actually run a test (it's a CodedUITest) the code doesn't get executed. I'm copying the code from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The application I'm working with, CSIS, has both ASP.net and Silverlight controls in it, but runs on my desktop. I think there may be some sort of issue with this because I found a warning on the [ClassInitializeAttribute Class website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx) - halfway down the page in a yellow box - ...

Comment: ...saying, "This attribute should not be used on ASP.NET unit tests, that is, any test with [HostType("ASP.NET")] attribute. Because of the stateless nature of IIS and ASP.NET, a method decorated with this attribute may be called more than once per test run."

Comment: I've updated the question with some new information, let me know if you have any information about it.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have your current tests within methods marked with the TestMethod attributes? If so, you can simply past the new ClassInit method into the same class. (Although by the sounds of it you may need to embed the "single instance" tests you were considering earlier... but at least it's in one place and not polluting your actual tests). If not, then I may have misunderstood your testing setup.

Comment: I've attached the code to the question in it I tried entering in the code right above the "[TestMethod]" but there's some sort of error. Am I implementing it wrong?

From my understanding the current tests are market with the TestMethod attribute. It's automatically done when you record your tests with the CodedUITest Builder.